# Invalid Redirect: uses a forbidden domain, when Authorized redirect URI for Google Client ID Web App

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-signin

**CURRENTLY**

I have a google apps script html page that incorporates Google Sign In

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top" />
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="111222333444555666777888999.apps.googleusercontent.com">

</head>
<body>
.
.
.
```

This script successfully brings up the google sign in:
[image: HTML correctly renders]

**ISSUE**

Clicking on the Sign in returns the following error message:

[image: Error message on clicking login]

I then try to add the URI either to `Authorized Javascript Origins` or `Authorized Redirect URIs`, but get the following error `Invalid redirect: uses a forbidden domain`

[image: Error message in GCP console]

**QUESTION**

1. Am I doing something obviously wrong?
2. I note that another user who posted [Google apps script oauth URI mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62927323/google-apps-script-oauth-uri-mismatch) did not get `Invalid Redirect: uses a forbidden domain` error message when they added a similar URI. They wrote "I add https://n-z2mpomgsi6mxzkdegvwhypizz4zxupdihnp6udy-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com from my redirect uri mismatch error to the list of authorized javascript origin uris in the developer console because stackoverflow said so. This gets oauth working fine and dandy." Why is it they were able to do this, and I cannot?

Comment: do you own googleusercontent.com ?  put your own domain in there not someone elses

Comment: @DalmTo, I assume you mean to use my own domain in the URI? Where in the Google Documentation does it say you need put my own domain down for a redirect? Besides the point that (1) I have already tried this, and (2) there is another user on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62927323/google-apps-script-oauth-uri-mismatch who successful used googleusercontent.com, I have other apps built on other platforms that use apps script `google.com` as their URI.

Comment: Does this domain actually exist? Why do you need the ```Google Sign In``` button for your web app ?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf, which domain are you referring to? The one ending in `.googleusercontent.com`? I am not sure. It's the one mentioned by the Google Authorisation Error popup. I assume it's a working end point. I am using `Google Sign In` because I am trying to collect users' email addresses when they log into Google. I tried another method using `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` but it does not work due to execution of script by a different user. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66341605/google-apps-script-dogete-get-user-email

Comment: So your end goal is to get user's email when they access your web app right? You dont require this to be done exclusively with the Google Sign In button right?

Comment: @Wronski - I'm encountering this same issue and I'm wondering if you found a solution.

Comment: Jeez, people, googleusercontent.com is a special Google's domain from where user content (such as apps sceipt webapps) is served for security reasons.